# Google showing source code

Tags: search, google-search, lithium

I would like to know why google is showing source code for my site.

[Search Google](https://www.google.co.in/#q=site:siicrypto.com+siicrypto&filter=0)

The site is created in the PHP - Lithium framework. This happened when I added g11n support for language translations.

It usually shows the source of the file

```
public_html/siicrypto.com/libraries/lithium/g11n/Locale.php
```

Comment: [Search Google] link is https://www.google.co.in/#q=site:siicrypto.com+siicrypto&filter=0

Comment: Add /libraries to robots.txt file

Comment: OK! I understood it, but now how do I force Google bot to rectify and rescan it asap. I submitted the URLs affected in Google Webmaster tools.

Comment: Also added sitemap.xml for indexing.

Answer (score 3):

It is showing that code because at the time the page was crawled it was displaying an error, along with a stacktrace and this is what Google indexed.

See https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:SEHpmo4_jY8J:https://siicrypto.com/company/howitworks+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in

[image]